# Money Format Number VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, double, money-format

I'm trying to convert a mathematical result of money format example:

```
Dim num1 As Integer = 2000
Dim num2 As Integer = 500

msgbox(cDbl(num1 + num2))
```

It only returns 2500, which I need to return my 2,500.00
if anyone has any idea how I would be very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `MsgBox` shows you the value, but it hasn't formatted it, as you haven't asked it to.

If you went a little further and *formatted the result as a string*, you'll get the format you desire, e.g:

```
Dim num1 As Double = 2000
Dim num2 As Double = 500
Dim sum As Double = num1 + num2

MsgBox(sum.ToString("0.00")) ' Adjust format string to suit
```

Comment: your answer is correct, but there is some way to add the commas? (2,500.00) Thanks :)

Comment: That's why I said "adjust format string to suit" the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) is quite through and even allows specifically for [currencies to be specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

First, you should use `Decimal` instead of `Double` when handling monetary values. `Double` has some rounding issues.

Second, you can use [string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
Dim num1 As Integer = 2000
Dim num2 As Integer = 500
Diml value As Decimal = CDec(num1 + num2)
Dim formattedValue As String = String.Format("{0:n}", value)

msgbox(formattedValue)
```

Answer (score 5):

[Standard Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

is a great resource for general number formatting, the top one being currency (this takes into account culture differences)

"C" or "c" for Currency

- Supported by: All numeric types.
- Precision specifier: Number of decimal digits.
- Default precision specifier: Defined by System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.

More information: The Currency ("C") Format Specifier.

- 123.456 ("C", en-US) -> $123.46
- 123.456 ("C", fr-FR) -> 123,46 €
- 123.456 ("C", ja-JP) -> ¥123
- -123.456 ("C3", en-US) -> ($123.456)
- -123.456 ("C3", fr-FR) -> -123,456 €
- -123.456 ("C3", ja-JP) -> -¥123.456

Answer (score 3):

If you want the format to be currency, either of these will work:

```
    Dim num1 As Integer = 2000
    Dim num2 As Integer = 500
    MsgBox(String.Format("{0:C2}", num1 + num2))
```

Or

```
    Dim num1 As Integer = 2000
    Dim num2 As Integer = 500
    Dim sum As Integer = num1 + num2

    MsgBox(sum.ToString("C2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**formatcurrency to double**

```
value = 1500,20 TL

ctype(value, double)

return 1500,20
```

**double to formatcurrency**

**sample**

```
value = 1500,1995

formatcurrency(value,2)

return = 1500,20 TL moneysembol (TL , $ ,vs..)
```

Comment: If you're pasting code in your answer use the {} tag to get it syntax highlighted. It'll make your answer much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim num1 As Decimal = 20
Dim num2 As Decimal = 34
Dim ans As Decimal

ans = num1 + num2
MsgBox(ans.ToString("c"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the String.Format documentation, you will find what you need there.

Answer (score -1):

You normally don't use `Integer` as the Datatype for currency values. Use `Double` instead.

I'm sure there are many ways to format the output string as a currency value.

One if the methods I know has already been explained by Rowland Shaw. So I'll skip to the other one. It is the built-in function called `FormatCurrency`. It will output the string as a currency value *plus* with the currency symbol defined in your system.

```
Dim num1 As Double = 2000
Dim num2 As Double = 500
Dim ans As Double = num1 + num2

MessageBox.Show(FormatCurrency(ans))
```

More details on `FormatCurrency`, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3352e6f5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: downvote - double is not a good datatype for currency values.  There can be rounding issues.  The Decimal type should be used instead.